# Server start method throws exception, port already in use?

Tags: c#, server, client, port

I am creating a server-client application where the server and client can talk to each other.
When I call the start method on the server, i get an error saying this:

```
Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted
```

Here is Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace NetworkingTest {
    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {

            bool readLine = true;
            string input = "";

            while (true) {
                if (readLine == true) {
                    input = Console.ReadLine();
                }

                if (input == "server") {
                    Server server = new Server(IPAddress.Any, 12346);
                    readLine = false;
                }

                if (input == "client") {
                    Client client = new Client(IPAddress.Parse("myipv4"), 12346);
                    readLine = false;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Here is Server.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace NetworkingTest {
    class Server {
        public TcpListener server;

        public Server (IPAddress ip, int port) {
            server = new TcpListener(ip, port);
            server.Start();

            Thread serverRunThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunServer));

            serverRunThread.Start();
        }

        void RunServer () {
            while (true) {
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Client connected!");

                Thread serverHandlerThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClient));
                serverHandlerThread.Start(client);
            }
        }

        void HandleClient(object c) {
            TcpClient client = (TcpClient)c;
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

            int i;
            string data = null;
            byte[] bytes = new byte[256];

            while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)  {   
              data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
              Console.WriteLine("Received: " + data);       
            }

            stream.Close();
            client.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

And here is Client.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;

namespace NetworkingTest {
    class Client {
        public TcpClient client;

        public Client (IPAddress ip, int port) {
            client = new TcpClient();
            client.Connect(ip, port);

            Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ConnectToServer));
            thread.Start();
        }

        void ConnectToServer () {
            while (true) {
                string input = Console.ReadLine();

                if (input == "exit" || input == "quit" || input == "close") {
                    break;
                } else {
                    SendMessageToServer(input);
                }
            }
        }

        void SendMessageToServer (string message) {
            NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
There was a problem in Program.cs, fixed while loop:

```
        while (readLine == true) {
            input = Console.ReadLine();

            if (input == "server") {
                Server server = new Server(IPAddress.Any, 12346);
                readLine = false;
            }

            if (input == "client") {
                Client client = new Client(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.5"), 12346);
                readLine = false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Each connection must have a unique combination of following : 1) Source IP 2) Destination IP 3) port number.  When the server and client are on the same PC an error can occur.  So do following : 1) Server listens to IPAnyAddress with port number.  2) The client connects to IP address of Server.  IPAnyAddress solves issue because the IP address isn't the same in Server as the client.

Comment: Note that your code is not fixed - it still has infinite while loop, just now it does nothing but waste your CPU resources.

Comment: Ok now it should be fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because of the error in your `while(true)` loop. First you ask user for a line with `Console.ReadLine()`. If `input` is "server" you start your server, BUT then you go to the beginning of your while loop and your `readLine` variable is false, and `input` is still "server", so it creates second server (basically you have infinite loop). Since you already have one sever on this port - second try fails with the error you see.

To fix, remove while loop, or do it more correctly, like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    while (true) {
        Console.WriteLine("Type \"server\" to start server, type \"client\" to start client, type \"exit\" to exit");
        string input = Console.ReadLine();

        if (input == "server") {
            Server server = new Server(IPAddress.Any, 12346);
        }
        else if (input == "client") {
            Client client = new Client(IPAddress.Parse("myipv4"), 12346);
        }
        else if (input == "exit")
            return;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated the question with the fixed code. :)